# Is Encoding not an enumeration?

Tags: c#, encoding, enums

I'm trying to figure out a way to store the encoding of a file in a database to then be able to retrieve it back into it's original type (System.Text.Encoding). But i'm getting an error I don't understand.

As a test, I created this small program to reproduce the error:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object o = Encoding.Unicode;
            Encoding enc = (Encoding) Enum.Parse(typeof(Encoding), o.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get in the Parse line says:

```
Type provided must be an Enum.
Parameter name: enumType
```

So, basically as far as I understand is telling me that `typeof(Encoding)` does not return an Enum type?
Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I changed to this:  
---
            `object o = Encoding.Unicode.CodePage;
            Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(int.Parse(o.ToString()));`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not an enum. It is a class with static properties. Something like this:

```
public class Encoding
{
    public static Encoding ASCII
    {
         get
         {
             //This is purely illustrative. It is not actually implemented like this
             return new ASCIIEncoding();
         }
    }
}
```

If you want to store the encoding in the database, store the code page:

```
int codePage = SomeEncoding.CodePage;
```

And use `Encoding.GetEncoding(theCodePage)` to get the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. Right-click, go to definition shows that Encoding is defined like this:

```
public abstract class Encoding : ICloneable
```

Answer (score 1):

`Encoding.Unicode` and `Encoding.ASCII` are static readonly properties of the class `Encoding`. They are not `enum` members.

You could instead store the `CodePage` of the encoding in the database, and retrieve it using [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx):

```
// store the encoding
WriteToDatabase(myEncoding.CodePage);

// retrieve the encoding used
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(/* value from the database */);
```

<sub>*This may not be a sound strategy for storing data of different encodings...however, I don't know exactly what you're working to accomplish in the big picture.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, yes i figured that was the way

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding` is a class and not enumeration. Calling `Encoding.Unicode` is calling a public property.
This line is wrong:

```
Encoding enc = (Encoding) Enum.Parse(typeof(Encoding), o.ToString());
```

If you look at [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) you will see that the first parameter should be enumType and you are passing totally different object.